# How to detect a taxonomy term in wordpress?

Tags: wordpress, custom-taxonomy

I want to detect the taxonomy term from my site url. For exampe if u consider this url, http://xxxxyyzzz.com/medicines/tablets/
I can detect the taxonomy 'medicines' but am unable to detect the taxonomy term 'tablets' using this code..

`if(is_tax( 'medicines', 'tablets'))
            {
                echo "You are on tablet page";
            }`

Comment: i have added the piece of code

Answer (score 1):

I'm a little confused by your question but I'll try to answer it as best I can.

"I want to detect the taxonomy term from my site url.". You're going about this in the wrong way. You'd end up with an incredibly long conditional if you tried using `is_tax()` for each term.

There are different ways you may want to approach this depending on where you're placing the code. Example:

```
// Check we're on a term page for the medicines taxonomy.
if ( is_tax( 'medicines' ) ) { // consider a singular name?

    // Get the current term object.
    $term = get_queried_object();

    // do something with the term...
    echo $term->name;

}
```